# Process termination by his parent or other processes

Tags: operating-system, terminate

Does an only father process can terminate (kill) his children? Or even another process without any relation to that specific process can kill it?

which processes can kill the specific process?

Comment: You never used 'kill -9' on linux or Task Manager 'End process' on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any process that has process ID of another process with same user-id can terminate it by sending a `SIGQUIT` signal to that process using 
`kill(pid, SIGQUIT)`.
You need to include `<sys/types.h>`
and `<signal.h>` for using this system call.

It is stated on [man page of kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

> For a process to have permission to send a signal it must either be privileged (under Linux: have the CAP_KILL capability), or the real or effective user ID of the sending process must equal the real or saved set-user-ID of the target process. In the case of SIGCONT it suffices when the sending and receiving processes belong to the same session.

Comment: @MartinJames In Windows, processes don't really have parents. So I supposed this question could not be asked about Windows.